# Updated android and gradle now getting error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android

I just updated android studio and the gradle, but now when i try running the app i get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not open local jar classpath snapshot write cache (C:\Users\Richi\Documents\Android Studio Project\AppMaster\.gradle\2.14.1\tasks\_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localJarClasspathSnapshot).
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
```

not sure whats going on!!

Comment: Turn it off and on again :)

Comment: sorry, not sure what you mean,

Answer (score 1):

Delete the .gradle folder and restart android studio.